# Clickhouse - Latest Record

Tags: clickhouse

We have almost 1B records in a replicated merge tree table.

1. The primary key is a,b,c
2. Our App keeps writing into this table with every user action. (we accumulate almost a million records per hour)
3. We append (store) the latest timestamp (updated_at) for a given unique combination of (a,b)

The key requirement is to provide a roll-up against the latest timestamp for a given combination of a,b,c

Currently, we are processing the queries as

```sql
select a,b,c, sum(x), sum(y)...etc
from table_1
where (a,b,updated_at) in (select a,b,max(updated_at) from table_1 group by a,b)
and c in (...)
group by a,b,c
```

clarification on the sub-query

```
(select a,b,max(updated_at) from table_1 group by a,b)

^ This part is for illustration only.. our app writes latest updated_at for every a,b implying that the clause shown above is more like 

(select a,b,updated_at from tab_1_summary)

[where tab_1_summary has latest record for a given a,b]
```

Note: We have to keep the grouping criteria as-is.

The table is structured with **partition (c) order by (a, b, updated_at)**

Question is, is there a way to write a better query. (that can returns results faster..we are required to shave off few seconds from the overall processing)

FYI: We toyed working with Materialized View ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree. But, given the size of this table, and constant inserts + the FINAL clause doesn't necessarily work well as compared to the query above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just for test try to use *join* instead of *tuple in (tuples)*:

```sql
select t.a, t.b, t.c, sum(x), sum(y)...etc 
from table_1 AS t inner join tab_1_summary using (a, b, updated_at) 
where c in (...) 
group by t.a, t.b, t.c
```

Consider using [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree/) to pre-calculate result metrics:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW table_1_mv
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree() 
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(updated_at) 
ORDER BY (updated_at, a, b, c)
AS SELECT
    updated_at,
    a,b,c, 
    sum(x) AS x, /* see [SimpleAggregateFunction data type](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/simpleaggregatefunction/) */
    sum(y) AS y,
    /* For non-simple functions should be used [AggregateFunction data type](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/data-types/aggregatefunction/). */
    // etc..
FROM table_1 
GROUP BY updated_at, a, b, c;
```

And use this way to get result:

```sql
select a,b,c, sum(x), sum(y)...etc
from table_1_mv
where (updated_at,a,b) in (select updated_at,a,b from tab_1_summary)
    and c in (...)    
group by a,b,c
```

Comment: Thank you Vladmir, sincerely appreciate your response. 
This whole clause comes relatively free to us implying that our app writes in separate area the latest "updated_at" for a,b .. it was my bad that in order to explain the problem, I ended up putting that in a sub-query.

 (
    select a, b, max(updated_at )
    from table_1_mv
    group by a, b)

The issue we are grappling with is the "where (a,b,updated_at) in" this is the part that is slowing down the response drastically... i.e., adds 3-4 secs

Comment: @calgs is *table_1* a distributed table? which sharding key is defined?